# Bluetooth LE only for paired Devices on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, delphi, bluetooth-lowenergy

I developed an Open-IoT Sensor with BLE-Hardware (Nordic CPU, https://github.com/joembedded/Open-SDI12-Blue ), which works excellent and I can access it easily (and without pairing) via Web-Bluetooth API (HTML/JS) an Windows and Android.

Now, while trying the same in RAD Studio C++ (using Windows 11), it seems ONLY paired devices are accepted for "DiscoverServices()", (unpaired raise an Exception). This makes (especially for BLE) no sense...

I recognised a flag in the Windows Settings to "allow this for special APPs", like MS LE Explorer.

I found for the "TBluetoothLEDevice*" entry a Flag "Paired"
[Screenshot from Windows Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPnFQ.png)

Does anybody know, if there is a automatic solution?

Thanks for your help!
Jo (JoEmbedded.de)

```
    //This is from the RAD Studio BLE-Scanner-Demo (just C, but Data is same for Delphi)

    void __fastcall TTPDiscoverServices::Invoke(void){
        TBluetoothLE *BLEh =  FForm->BluetoothLE1;
        TBluetoothLEDeviceList *DLh = BLEh->DiscoveredDevices;
        TBluetoothLEDevice* BTDev=  DLh->Items[FForm->ListBox1->ItemIndex];
        bool bres;
        if(!BTDev->Paired){
            bres=false;
            ::MessageBox(NULL,L"Device not paired?",L"**Error**",MB_OK);
        }else{
            //original: if(!FForm->BluetoothLE1->DiscoveredDevices->Items[FForm->ListBox1->ItemIndex]->DiscoverServices())
            bres = BTDev->DiscoverServices(); // Jo: Exception Win11 for unpaired Devices
            ::MessageBox(NULL,bres?L"Discover OK":L"Discover Error",L"**Discover**",MB_OK);
        }
        if(!bres) TThread::Synchronize(NULL, SynchronizeProc);
    }
```

Comment: Not sure how it is implemented in RAD Studio but you must use WinRT BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher class to find BLE devices (as we do in our Bluetooth Framework)

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the hint. Embarcadero says, they are using WinRT..

Comment: What is the exception message? Or type?

Comment: Hi Mike, Exeption is "Can not DiscoverServices for unpaired Devices". However, I recently recognised, that for Embarcadero still Android-64Bit Support is missing, so I continue in the meantime with my WebBluetooth-Implementation, wich works fine....

Comment: They have updated BluetoothLE support in RAD Studio 11. You can download Trial version and check there.